# How to extract the x-value of a singularity in NDSolveValue?

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

In solving an ODE numerically in Mathematica using `NDSolveValue` the system detects a singularity. To analyse this behaviour I would like to extract the x-value of the singularity.

```
y = 12.916241980643031
ufin = Block[{ϵ = $MachineEpsilon}, 
   NDSolveValue[{u'[x] == x^2*(Sinh[ξ[x]/4])^3*f[ξ[x]],
     ξ'[x] == -1/((Cosh[ξ[x]] - 4 Cosh[ξ[x]/2] + 3) x) ((Sinh[ξ[x]/4])^3*f[ξ[x]] + 
         1/32 (Sinh[ξ[x]] - 8 Sinh[ξ[x]/2] + 3 ξ[x]))*(u[x] + 1/32 (Sinh[ξ[x]] - 8 Sinh[ξ[x]/2] + 
            3 ξ[x]) x^3)*(x - 1/16 u[x])^-1,
     ξ[ϵ] == 2.9, u[ϵ] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[ξ[x] <= 0, "StopIntegration"]}, 
    u, {x, ϵ, 10000}]];
```

(Note that the small `Epsilon` instead of zero is necessary as otherwise it runs into `1/0`'s.)

The function `f[ξ[x]]` was beforehand defined as

```
f[\[Xi]_] := (3 (Sinh[\[Xi]] - \[Xi]))/(32 (Sinh[\[Xi]/4])^3)
```

Comment: If I understand right (I am on a phone), you would use Lasr[ufin[“Grid”]] to get the last step’s x value. You could also use ufin[“Domain”].

Comment: The function `f` is undefined, and `u[y]` should be `u[x]`.  By the way, I believe that @MichaelE2 meant `Last[ufin[“Grid”]] `.

Comment: Thank you @Michael E2 and @bbgodfrey,`Last[ufin[“Grid”]]` worked!